# SVN Commit regulations

Tags: svn, commit

Should commits be made only if the solution compiles and builds successfully? are "mid-way" commits acceptable in very large changes that leave the code not working for say, a few hours?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes it is acceptable.

Version control is for version control; not backup. You should have something separate in place for dealing with backups of compilable code which may indeed circle back around to the version control system.

Either way forcing a developer to *wait* to check in code is **an impending disaster of lost code at some point**.

Comment: +1. I agree. Commit as often as possible. Don't over think it. Just commit as much as you can. I find that there are only benefits and no downsides to committing often.

Comment: +1. I agree as well.  You don't want developers going out developing in a cave then tossing a pile of bits and bytes to other programmers while saying "Have fun!"  I worked at one company that had a policy if you lost more than a days worth or work (virus, hard drive crashed, laptop stolen, etc), depending on the circumstance and other factors, it could be a fire-able offense.

Comment: @jgifford25 Eee-yikes!! Hope you were well compensated for that stress … I think I'd go nuts worrying …

Comment: Right. +1. And if you're afraid that committing too often will break too much stuff, switch to something like *git*, or have each developer use a separate branch and merge up to the trunk when stuff compiles, as @Luke Maurer suggests.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought... just wanted to made sure, as you say. Waiting to check in could result in a far larger problem than not having compilable code for download from the repo (aka. losing hours of work)

Comment: I disagree with Dave, commit is not save function. i prefer to commit when I finish coding something and I can write cool comment to that commit(you dont write commits if you use it as  save)

Comment: @01 Sure, commit isn't save. A commit should be some cohesive unit of work that stands alone (the so-called atomicity issue).

The issue here isn't so much the *size* of the commit so much as how stringent the other requirements on it are. We're saying that not breaking the build is less important than it's often taken to be. The ideal size of a commit is a separate (but related) question.

Comment: My team has a rule that all devs commit their work near the end of the day as long as their code compiles, and they must stay to ensure that the on-commit build triggered in TeamCity completes successfully. If a milestone is reached, the code is tagged. If a dev needs to be insulated from having to care about breaking the build, they can work on a feature branch; just as long as their work gets into the repository before they leave. This policy has saved our bacon many times.

Answer (score 5):

Ensuring that code doesn't stay broken for too long is the job of [continuous integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), not version control.

Comment: and even if your company doesnt believe in CI you can put it on one of your machines(its just one war in JEE and It wont slow you down).

Comment: If your company is control-freakish enough to demand that trunk always compile, CI should be their wet dream … it enforces that trunk can compile *and* fingers the culprit within minutes …

Comment: I think the question is about setting policy (e.g. "thou shall not commit breaking changes"), not about technical reinforcement of that policy.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Brian and Aaron's comments, I would only add that even this tradeoff between stability and up-to-date code can be mitigated using branches or, as a more extreme solution, a decentralized system like Git. “Commit often and let the build bot find errors” is my favorite policy, but if you need a more stable place to check out code from, a branch is what you want (but of course someone has to maintain it).

Comment: I recommend this methodology to my team members.  It removes the fear of breaking the build (since the feature branch isn't usually being automatically built) while also providing the security of having the changes in the repository.  It also helps my team learn how to merge their code better since I encourage them to reintegrate their own feature branches.

Comment: @arcain Are you using SVN's built-in merge management? How well does that work? I ask because we got burned by a messy feature merge a few months back, and we were stuck sorting it out by hand since we were running an old SVN version.

Comment: We use TortoiseSVN, and I've never had a merge flat-out fail with an error, but we've had cases of operator error by a committer where accidental commits to a branch necessitated a rollback of just a few revisions. Reintegrating the branch automatically wasn't an option since the full revision range couldn't be merged back to the parent, so we had to cherrypick revision ranges. In some of these cases, it was just easier to ignore the rev merged into the working copy from the branch, mark the conflicts as resolved, and just manually merge the changes.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it depends on the kind of VCS that is used:

- if you're using a **centralized** one like SVN, I'd tend to say **yes, it is acceptable** following [Aarons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572310/svn-commit-regulations/4572324#4572324) arguments.
- if you're running a **DVCS** like Git, I would say **no, it isn't acceptable** because every developer can do his local commits, test the implementation and then push back to the (bare) public repo once his work is done.

Since you tagged your question *svn*, follow [Aaron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572310/svn-commit-regulations/4572324#4572324).

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is important to at least *try* to not commit breaking changes. More so if the team is larger, or the pace of development is faster. The idea is that all members of the team stay up to date with the latest changes. **Nobody should be afraid of doing a `svn update` after each commit by a team member**.

This is impossible if the latest version regularly has compilation errors. Even a failing test can be annoying, because it is not always easy to tell if a problem was introduced by your uncommitted changes or the ones you just received by the `svn update`. Work grinds to a halt as everybody tries to figure out why suddenly things aren't working anymore.

Breaking changes will also interfere with your ability to [bisect the source code history](http://mindinthewater.blogspot.com/2010/12/bisect-your-source-code-history-to-find.html). So even if you work alone or on feature branches, it can still be valuable to avoid them.

A policy to avoid breaking changes does not have to contradict with regular small commits. Big changes can almost always be split up into a list of smaller tasks, each of which can be completed with a modest size commit that does not break the build. This has the added advantage that conflicts are reduced. I tend to put things like this in my commit messages for such smaller tasks:

> - towards fixing *xyz*: refactored *fuzz* in preperation of *aspect foo*
> - towards fixing *xyz*: *aspect foo* now works
> - fixed *xyz*: *aspect bar* now works